# How completion "git add" full path in zsh?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh

Git add  not list all file, only give a layer of a layer to choose file.

Such as

```
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                ├── A.java
                └── B.java
```

if I type `$ git add <tab>`

it will be

```
$ git add src/main/java/com/A.java
A.java  B.java
```

How to do this:

```
$ git add <tab>
src/main/java/com/A.java
src/main/java/com/B.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Autocompletion in `zsh` already put for you the path until there is a difference and only shows you what is different. At the end once you've confirmed/chosen the one you want, the whole path will be printed. To circle through the propositions, you keep pressing the `TAB` key.

In your example there are only 2 files, and the difference only starts with the file name A or B. This is why it writes it for you. If you want the other file, just press `TAB` again and your input will be changed accordingly.